# Any tools to find sentences or usages by inputing grammatical patterns?

Tags: language, patternmatching

In [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/180830/10484) I asked how I can find a verb that can lead the entity *information retrieval* in a formal way. Any such tools?

Answer (score 1):

From [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/is-there-an-online-sample-sentence-database-or-search-engine), do a Google search, but put a tilde ("~") in front of the word you're unsure of.

e.g. `~do information retrieval`